# List of Categories in a feed

Tags: wordpress

I am building a mobile app for my wordpress site. I am planning to read the RSS feed from the website and display it using the mobile app. For this first I need a list of categories to be displayed on the home page and when the user selects a category, the posts in the category is displayed. I know how to get category specific RSS feed, but couldn't find a way so that I can get a list of all categories available on the website. Are there any plugins available which does this?

Any help will will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer JSON over RSS feed.

To enable Wordpress output JSON just install [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/)

Then you can use it to browse categories and then posts on categories. For example on my own blog:

Categories

```
http://www.tapanila.net/api/get_category_index/
```

Posts from category Index 1

```
http://www.tapanila.net/api/get_category_posts?category_id=1
```

[Whole documentation](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/)

Comment: Thanks Teemu... Indeed JSON is a much better option... I checked this plugin but again didn't see any option to list categories...

Comment: Just added samples from my own blog

Comment: Awesome! Works on my site too now!  Thanks a ton!